# What is the inverse function of $y=\cos^2(x)$, $x\in[\pi/2 , \pi]$?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

I am trying to answer the following question:

> - What is the inverse function of $y=\cos^2(x)$, $x\in[0 , \pi/2]$?
> - What is the inverse function of $y=\cos^2(x)$,  $x\in[\pi/2 , \pi]$?

I answered the first by "solving for $x$" and obtained $x=\arccos(\sqrt{y})$, which seems to work just fine. As $0=\arccos(\sqrt{1})$ and $\pi/2=\arccos(\sqrt{0})$ but for the other ones, it didn't work very well. I tried to write:

$$\arccos(\sqrt{0})+a=\pi/2\\\arccos(\sqrt{1})+a=\pi/2$$

Which clearly won't work. The answer turned out to be

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\arccos(2x-1)\quad\quad\quad  y=\pi -\frac{1}{2}\arccos(2x-1)$$

for the first and second questions.Now, this hinted me the following idea - for example - in the second case I should write:

$$a\cdot \arccos(bx+c)+d=\pi/2 \\ a\cdot \arccos(bx+c)+d=\pi$$

And find coefficients $a,b,c,d$ such that both equations are satisfied. The trouble is: I kinda understood how one can arrive at that the answers I mentioned: When $x=0$, we have $\arccos(-1)=\pi$ and when $x=1$, we have $\arccos(1)=0$ so we need to find:

$$\pi a + d = \pi/2 \\ 0a+d=\pi$$

With this, we find the function given in the answer. I've conjectured that we could also - for example - choose another polynomial function such that $x=0 \implies f(0)=-1$ and $x=1 \implies f(1)=0$ and then:

$$a\cdot \arccos(f(0))+d=\pi/2 \\ a\cdot \arccos(f(1))+d=\pi$$

Which then yields:

$$a\cdot \pi+d=\pi/2 \\ a\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}+d=\pi$$

And again, we could solve for $a,d$ and find it but this procedure does not work. I am confused: Why does that solution works but the one in my conjecture doesn't?

Comment: Note $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1$, so you can use $\cos^2(x) = \frac{\cos(2x) + 1}{2}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Is there a reason to prefer this to compute the inverse instead of $y=\arccos(\sqrt{x})$? I thought about it but the domain of the inverse function is $[0,1]$, it seemed square roots wouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: The issue with using $x=\arccos(\sqrt{y})$ is you have to be careful with whether it's the positive or negative square root of $y$ that you should be taking the arccos of, i.e., whether $\cos(x)$ is positive or negative. You can see it's positive for $x \in [0, \pi/2)$ but negative  for $x \in (\pi/2, \pi]$. Using what I suggested instead avoids dealing with that particular issue.